# Can an SVN server be recovered from a working copy checkout?

Tags: svn, backup

we have lost our SVN server, the hard drive just died.

We have a huge project, and we got a 2 months old back up,

I'm wondering if it would be possible to restore a new SVN server 
from our local folder information, which I believe it keep all 
revisions.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion working copies, unlike git or hg clones, do not contain your revision history. Maybe some cached log history (depending on what client you use), but no revision details; just pristine copies of the items so you can do a compare of your changes vs. the last known state from the repository.

You have a 2 month old backup, and whatever current state you can cobble together from your existing WCs. Everything in between is gone. Once you've put things back together, you'll need to check out fresh WCs too.

It's a very difficult lesson to learn.